# Unwanted Event Override

Tags: javascript, for-loop, hyperlink, event-handling, dom-events

Here is my code (simplified):

```
function FillTable ( oProfile_data ) {

    var oTable = document.getElementById ( "table" );

    for ( var key in oProfile_data ) {

        var oRow = oTable.insertRow ( oTable.rows.length );
        var oCell = oRow.insertCell ( 0 );

        var oLink = document.createElement ( "a" );
            oLink.href = "javascript:void(0)";
            oLink.innerHTML = "Visit Homepage";

            oLink.addEventListener ( "click",
            function () {
                var win = window.open ( oProfile_data [key]["url"], "_blank" );
                win.focus();
            }, false );

        oCell.appendChild ( oLink );
    }
}
```

The problem is that every row has a link to the same document and I can't figure out why!

My temporary solution is:

```
oLink.href = "javascript:void(0); var win = window.open ( \"" + oProfile_data [key]["url"] + "\", \"_blank\" ); win.focus();";
```

Which works fine.
I suppose it is an event overriding problem but I may be wrong.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem that can be solved through an understanding of *closures*.  Your anonymous function (bound to the *click* event) doesn't get called until the user clicks on the link, and when this line gets executed:

```
var win = window.open ( oProfile_data [key]["url"], "_blank" );
```

The value of `key` will be enclosed by the `FillTable` function.  So, it will retain the value that it had when the function ended (ie, the last value it held in the loop).

You'll have to create a new closure for each iteration of the loop.  Something like:

```
oLink.addEventListener ("click",
(function (k) {
    return function () {
       var win = window.open ( oProfile_data [k]["url"], "_blank" );
       win.focus();
    }
 }
)(key), false);
```

Above, we create a function that *returns* a function that opens your window.  Then, we pass the value of `key` into that function, thus creating a new closure.